# "No such file or directory error" while combining multiple excel sheets using python os and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operating-system

I am using in python the code below to combine several identically structured excel files into only one big file:

```html
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/Helvio/historico') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
print(files)
## Method 1 gets the first sheet of a given file
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel('momentum_cons.xlsx')
```

I can see that cwd is pointing at the right place, as when I print(cwd) I can see the files on the working directory:

```html
['volume_20141230.xlsx', 'volume_20150130.xlsx', 'volume_20150227.xlsx', 'volume_20150331.xlsx', 'volume_20150430.xlsx', 'volume_20150529.xlsx', 'volume_20150630.xlsx', 'volume_20150731.xlsx', 'volume_20150831.xlsx', 'volume_20150930.xlsx', 'volume_20151030.xlsx', 'volume_20151130.xlsx', 'volume_20151230.xlsx', 'volume_20160129.xlsx', 'volume_20160229.xlsx', 'volume_20160331.xlsx', 'volume_20160429.xlsx', 'volume_20160531.xlsx', 'volume_20160630.xlsx', 'volume_20160729.xlsx', 'volume_20160831.xlsx', 'volume_20160930.xlsx', 'volume_20161031.xlsx', 'volume_20161130.xlsx', 'volume_20161229.xlsx', 'volume_20170131.xlsx', 'volume_20170224.xlsx', 'volume_20170331.xlsx', 'volume_20170428.xlsx', 'volume_20170531.xlsx', 'volume_20170630.xlsx', 'volume_20170731.xlsx', 'volume_20170831.xlsx', 'volume_20170929.xlsx', 'volume_20171031.xlsx', 'volume_20171130.xlsx', 'volume_20171228.xlsx', 'volume_20180131.xlsx', 'volume_20180228.xlsx', 'volume_20180329.xlsx', 'volume_20180430.xlsx', 'volume_20180530.xlsx', 'volume_20180629.xlsx', 'volume_20180731.xlsx', 'volume_20180831.xlsx', 'volume_20180928.xlsx', 'volume_20181031.xlsx', 'volume_20181130.xlsx', 'volume_20181228.xlsx', 'volume_20190131.xlsx', 'volume_20190228.xlsx', 'volume_20190329.xlsx', 'volume_20190430.xlsx', 'volume_20190531.xlsx', 'volume_20190628.xlsx', 'volume_20190731.xlsx', 'volume_20190830.xlsx', 'volume_20190930.xlsx', 'volume_20191031.xlsx', 'volume_20191129.xlsx', 'volume_20191230.xlsx', 'volume_20200131.xlsx', 'volume_20200228.xlsx', 'volume_20200331.xlsx', 'volume_20200430.xlsx', 'volume_20200529.xlsx', 'volume_20200630.xlsx', 'volume_20200731.xlsx', 'volume_20200831.xlsx', 'volume_20200930.xlsx', 'volume_20201030.xlsx', 'volume_20201130.xlsx', 'volume_20201230.xlsx', 'volume_20210129.xlsx', 'volume_20210226.xlsx', 'volume_20210331.xlsx', 'volume_20210430.xlsx', 'volume_20210531.xlsx', 'volume_20210630.xlsx']
```

When I run the code above, though, I receive the following error:

```html
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 651, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'volume_20141230.xlsx'
```

Any thoughts how to handle it?

Comment: try absolute path `read_excel(os.path.join(cwd, file))`

Comment: Your code runs fine on my laptop. Maybe some permissions issue with the file ?

Comment: I done the suggestion of Lei Yang and it worked. Just have to change the 3rd line of the loop to this:

df = df.append(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(cwd, file)), ignore_index=True) 

Thanks Lei for the help.